# error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python

I have this error in my code, but I don't know why:

> File "C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/untitled8.py", line 25, in w3_corr
>       FXp=[(2.022-0.0004302*p)+(0.1722-0.0000984*p)*(math.exp(18.177-0.004129*p))*X]*(1.157-0.869*X)
>
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
>   TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Code:

```
import math



def w3_corr(X,p,Mflux,D,Hflux):


    FXp=0
    FXG=0
    FD=0
    Hflux_calc=0

    FXp=[(2.022-0.0004302*p)+(0.1722-0.0000984*p)*math.exp(18.177-0.004129*p)*X]*(1.157-0.869*X)
    FXG=(0.01484-1.596*X+0.1729*X*math.fabs(X))*(Mflux/10**6)+1.037
    FD=[0.2664+0.8357*math.exp(-3.151*D)]

    Hflux_calc= FXp * FXG * FD

    return Hflux_calc

y=w3_corr(0.15,14.5038,0,0.31496,90445.9)

print(y)
```

Comment: When you put square brackets `[]` around something, you make a list. If you're not trying to make a list, don't put square brackets there. Don't try and use square brackets for arithmetic grouping.

Comment: You are right, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you put square brackets `[]` around something, you make a list. If you're not trying to make a list, don't put square brackets there.

Use parentheses `()` for arithmetic grouping.